# Actualizar variables con NgZone Angular

Tags: angular

tengo implementado ngzone dentro del cual tengo un observable que actualiza los datos de la vista, en el siguiente ejemplo ilustro como seria mi codigo, el problema esta en que cuando intento modificar la variable number esta no actualiza la vista, como podria arreglar este problema o cual es el uso correcto de ngZone? cambiando runOutsideAngular por run funciona perfecto, entonces en que casos se debe usar uno u otro y como funciona la optimizacion que provee su implementacion?

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
      setTimeout(() => { //simulando observable
        this.number = 5435;
        console.log(this.number);
      }, 2000);
    });
  }
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gpfsxs

Answer (score 0):

la forma correcta seria la siguiente:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  setTimeout(() => { //simulando observable
  this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
    this.act(666)
  });
  }, 2000);
}
```

Comment: Deberias de detallar tu respuesta o podria ser eliminada.